# What does the sensor tag do?

Tags: sdformat, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I understand a **link** tag adds a block of matter into the simulation. The **joint** tag adds a connection between the two links. But what does the **sensor** tag actually do?

When look at this chunk of code for example

```
<sensor name='contact_sensor' type='contact'>
    <always_on>true</always_on>
    <update_rate>10</update_rate>
    <contact>
        <collision>caster_link_collision</collision>
        <topic>/gazebo/caster_bumper</topic>
    </contact>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_bumper_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_bumper.so">
        <frameName>world</frameName>
        <bumperTopicName>/gazebo/caster_bumper</bumperTopicName>
    </plugin>
</sensor>
```

This sensor loads a plugin. This plugin has a **bumperTopicName** tag with the same topic name as the **sensor** tag has in its **contacts/topic** tag. I can look into the plugin's source code and see what it does with it's tags. But I have no idea what happens with the information inside the **sensor** tag.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20900/what-does-the-sensor-tag-do?/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2018-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The `<sensor>` tag adds a sensor to the link, which usually publishes the sensor readings to a Gazebo Transport topic.

According to the configurations of your `contact` sensor, it will publish messages to the `/gazebo/caster_bumper` **Gazebo topic** whenever the link's `caster_link_collision` touches something. That's the sensor's basic functionality and it will work even if you remove the `<plugin>` tag.

Adding a plugin to a sensor lets the user extend the sensor's functionality directly in the C++ code. The referenced plugin library will be loaded together with the sensor and can tie callbacks to specific simulation events.

The functionality of plugin in your example is to publish **ROS messages** with the sensor readings. So the sensor on your example is *publishing to 2 different transport systems: Gazebo's and ROS*. The parameters inside the plugin tag only affect the plugin - in this case, they're setting the TF frame name for the readings, and the ROS topic name.

#### Update

Source code:

- The contact sensor class: [gazebo::sensors::ContactSensor](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/gazebo9/gazebo/sensors/ContactSensor.cc)
- The Gazebo-ROS bumper plugin: [gazebo::GazeboRosBumper](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/melodic-devel/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_bumper.cpp)

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2018-11-02**:
So is there a source code of the sensor available?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-11-02**:
updated the answer with links to the source code